# Versioning on + Workflows = error occured (SP server 2013)

Tags: sharepoint-server

Does anyone know if there is an official no no from Microsoft saying that if you have Versioning turned on and then go to add a workflow to the library it will error out?  This is my issue.  I've tested setting up two separate document libraries one with Versioning on and the other with it off.  The library with it on gives me Error Occurred in the workflow column, while the library without Versioning works like a charm with workflows and I get a In Progress.

So can anyone put my mind at ease or do I have something broken somewhere?

Comment: Having versioning enabled should not break the ability to start workflows

Comment: It sounds moreso like it might be workflow logic than using a library with versioning. What is your workflow doing?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Under the workflow status I just get a Error Occured.  No reason or anything... not sure where to look for Workflow logs.

Comment: I thought it might be the custom column I created but that looks ok.

Comment: The workflow tasklist Assigned to also has no selected for Allow multiple selections.  I am at a huge loss here.  I was trying to set up Workflow Manager on my SharePoint 2013 server so I could use the SP designer but I cannot get that to work either.  Workflows... big pain in the ass.